iOS Notification Sound Settings
I’m not sure why my custom sound, which is about 29 seconds long, disappears after about 8 seconds when the notification is triggered. What settings should I adjust to ensure the notification stays active with my 29-second sound? Do I need to modify the AppDelegate.swift or info.plist?
NotificationChannel(
  channelKey: "alarm_Category",
  channelName: "alarm_Category",
  channelDescription: 'Notification tests as alerts',
  defaultColor: Colors.blue,
  ledColor: Colors.white,
  playSound: true,
  onlyAlertOnce: false,
  importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
  soundSource: 'resource://raw/notification_sound',
  criticalAlerts: true,
  enableVibration: true,
  enableLights: true,
  ledOnMs: 1000,
  ledOffMs: 500,
  locked: true,
),


await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
          category: NotificationCategory.Alarm,
          fullScreenIntent: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          id: subId,
          channelKey: "alarm_Category",
          title: DateFormat('yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm').format(currentNotificationTime),
          body: 'Alarm Memo: ${schedule.enteredText}',
          payload: {
            'subId': subId.toString(),
            'enteredText': schedule.enteredText,
            'categoryIdentifier': "alarm_Category",
            'identifier': "alarm_Category",
            'channelKey': "alarm_Category",
            'category': "alarm_Category",
          },
          displayOnForeground: true,
          displayOnBackground: true,
          autoDismissible: false,
          locked: true,
          icon: 'resource://drawable/ic_launcher',
          customSound: 'resource://raw/notification_sound',
          showWhen: true,
          wakeUpScreen: true,
          criticalAlert: true,
        ),
        schedule: NotificationCalendar(
          repeats: true,
          preciseAlarm: true,
          year: currentNotificationTime.year,
          month: currentNotificationTime.month,
          day: currentNotificationTime.day,
          hour: currentNotificationTime.hour,
          minute: currentNotificationTime.minute,
          second: currentNotificationTime.second,
        ),
      );


Solution
1. Configure UNNotificationSound in AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import UserNotifications
import AVFoundation

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        // Configure notification settings
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [
                .alert,
                .badge,
                .sound,
                .criticalAlert  // Add critical alert permission
            ]
            
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: options,
                completionHandler: { _, _ in }
            )
        }
        
        // Configure audio session
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(
                .playback,
                mode: .default,
                options: [.mixWithOthers]
            )
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to set audio session category: \(error)")
        }
        
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}

// Add UNNotificationSoundName extension
extension UNNotificationSoundName {
    static let customSound = UNNotificationSoundName("notification_sound.wav")
}

2. Update Info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <!-- Other existing entries -->
    
    <!-- Add background modes -->
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    
    <!-- Add critical alerts entitlement -->
    <key>com.apple.developer.usernotifications.critical-alerts</key>
    <true/>
    
    <!-- Add notification service extension -->
    <key>com.apple.developer.usernotifications.time-sensitive</key>
    <true/>
    
    <!-- Configure audio session -->
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

3. Update Flutter Notification Configuration
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';

Future<void> initializeNotifications() async {
  await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    null,
    [
      NotificationChannel(
        channelKey: "alarm_Category",
        channelName: "Alarm Category",
        channelDescription: 'Long duration alarm notifications',
        defaultColor: Colors.blue,
        ledColor: Colors.white,
        playSound: true,
        soundSource: 'resource://raw/notification_sound',
        importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
        criticalAlerts: true,
        enableVibration: true,
        enableLights: true,
        locked: true,
        // Add these settings for iOS
        defaultRingtoneType: DefaultRingtoneType.Alarm,
        channelShowBadge: true,
      ),
    ],
    debug: true,
  );
}

Future<void> scheduleAlarmNotification({
  required int subId,
  required DateTime scheduledTime,
  required String memoText,
}) async {
  await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    content: NotificationContent(
      id: subId,
      channelKey: "alarm_Category",
      title: DateFormat('yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm').format(scheduledTime),
      body: 'Alarm Memo: $memoText',
      category: NotificationCategory.Alarm,
      notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Default,
      criticalAlert: true,
      fullScreenIntent: true,
      wakeUpScreen: true,
      autoDismissible: false,
      locked: true,
      displayOnForeground: true,
      displayOnBackground: true,
      customSound: 'resource://raw/notification_sound',
      // Add iOS specific settings
      timeoutAfter: Duration(seconds: 30), // Extend timeout
      payload: {
        'sound_duration': '29',  // Add sound duration info
        'critical': 'true',      // Mark as critical
      },
    ),
    schedule: NotificationCalendar(
      repeats: true,
      preciseAlarm: true,
      allowWhileIdle: true,
      year: scheduledTime.year,
      month: scheduledTime.month,
      day: scheduledTime.day,
      hour: scheduledTime.hour,
      minute: scheduledTime.minute,
      second: scheduledTime.second,
    ),
  );
}

4. Add Audio Processing Extension
Create a new Notification Service Extension target in Xcode:
// NotificationService.swift
import UserNotifications
import AVFoundation

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    override func didReceive(
        _ request: UNNotificationRequest,
        withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void
    ) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
        
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            // Configure sound
            if let soundDuration = request.content.userInfo["sound_duration"] as? String,
               let soundPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "notification_sound", ofType: "wav") {
                let soundUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: soundPath)
                bestAttemptContent.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "notification_sound.wav"))
                
                // Setup audio session
                do {
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                    
                    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundUrl)
                    audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                    audioPlayer?.play()
                } catch {
                    print("Error setting up audio: \(error)")
                }
            }
            
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
    
    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler,
           let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
}

5. Sound File Requirements

Convert your sound file to WAV format:

ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 44100 notification_sound.wav


Add the sound file to both:


Main app bundle
Notification Service Extension bundle

6. Entitlements Configuration

Add entitlements file to your project
Enable these capabilities:

Background Modes
Critical Alerts
Push Notifications



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.usernotifications.critical-alerts</key>
    <true/>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>

Best Practices

Sound File Optimization

// Check sound file properties
void validateSoundFile() {
  final file = File('notification_sound.wav');
  if (file.lengthSync() > 5 * 1024 * 1024) {
    print('Warning: Sound file too large');
  }
}


Error Handling

Future<bool> checkNotificationPermissions() async {
  final status = await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed();
  if (!status) {
    // Request permissions
    return await AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
  }
  return status;
}


Testing

void testNotification() async {
  final now = DateTime.now();
  await scheduleAlarmNotification(
    subId: 1,
    scheduledTime: now.add(Duration(seconds: 5)),
    memoText: 'Test notification',
  );
}

Remember to:

Test on real iOS devices
Request critical alert permission
Handle audio session properly
Optimize sound file size
Consider battery impact

Would you like me to explain any part in more detail?

Thank you for the answer.Is it absolutely necessary to enable ‘Critical Alerts’ in the capabilities section? I heard that Critical Alerts require approval from Apple. Is it mandatory to add Critical Alerts in the capabilities section?
